# unable to override styles in primeNG with style, styleClass, inputStyle or inputStyleClass Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, primeng

I was finally able to get primeNG working with angular-cli. In `.angular-cli.json I have:

```
  "styles": [
          "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
          "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

I am trying to use the `CalendarModule` like so:

```
import {CalendarModule} from "primeng/primeng";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CalendarModule
    ],
```

In the HTML I have the following:

```
<p-calendar styleClass="test" [(ngModel)]="validationDate" 
inputStyleClass="test" [showIcon]="true" dateFormat="dd.mm.yy"></pcalendar>
```

In the component css

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-validation',
    templateUrl: 'user-validation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['user-validation.component.css']
})
```

`user-validation.component.css`

```
.test{
    width: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Cannot find a question here

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi unable to override styles in primeNG with style, styleClass, inputStyle or inputStyleClass Angular-CLI

Comment: this might be due to the hierarchy of styles linked to your application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
/deep/ .test{
        width: 25px !important;
}
```

or

```
>>> .test{
width: 25px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me -

```
 <p-calendar name = "calendarMod" [showIcon]="true" [(ngModel)]="actionDate"  dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" [inputStyle] = "{'width':'85px'}" ></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above does not work, try to use:

```
::ng-deep .className
```